# Blogger : How To Improve Image Quality of Random Posts Widget (Code Added)

Tags: blogger

I found this code from:
https://helplogger.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/random-posts-widget-with-thumbnails-and-summary-for-blogger.html

This is the code i am using:

```html
<style>
#random-posts img {
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 3px;
    transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
}

#random-posts img:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

ul#random-posts {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

#random-posts a {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0px auto 5px;
}

#random-posts a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.random-summary {
    font-size: 11px;
    background: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

#random-posts li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    padding: 4px;
}
</style>
<ul id='random-posts'>
<script type='text/javaScript'>
var randomposts_number = 5;
var randomposts_chars = 110;
var randomposts_details = 'yes';
var randomposts_comments = 'Comments';
var randomposts_commentsd = 'Comments Disabled';
var randomposts_current = [];
var total_randomposts = 0;
var randomposts_current = new Array(randomposts_number);

function randomposts(json) {
    total_randomposts = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t
}
document.write('<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=0&callback=randomposts\"><\/script>');

function getvalue() {
    for (var i = 0; i < randomposts_number; i++) {
        var found = false;
        var rndValue = get_random();
        for (var j = 0; j < randomposts_current.length; j++) {
            if (randomposts_current[j] == rndValue) {
                found = true;
                break
            }
        };
        if (found) {
            i--
        } else {
            randomposts_current[i] = rndValue
        }
    }
};

function get_random() {
    var ranNum = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * (total_randomposts - 1));
    return ranNum
};
</script>
<script type='text/javaScript'> 
function random_posts(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < randomposts_number; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        var randompoststitle = entry.title.$t;
        if ('content' in entry) {
            var randompostsnippet = entry.content.$t
        } else {
            if ('summary' in entry) {
                var randompostsnippet = entry.summary.$t
            } else {
                var randompostsnippet = "";
            }
        };
        randompostsnippet = randompostsnippet.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
        if (randompostsnippet.length < randomposts_chars) {
            var randomposts_snippet = randompostsnippet
        } else {
            randompostsnippet = randompostsnippet.substring(0, randomposts_chars);
            var whitespace = randompostsnippet.lastIndexOf(" ");
            randomposts_snippet = randompostsnippet.substring(0, whitespace) + "&#133;";
        };
        for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++) {
            if ('thr$total' in entry) {
                var randomposts_commentsnum = entry.thr$total.$t + ' ' + randomposts_comments
            } else {
                randomposts_commentsnum = randomposts_commentsd
            }; if (entry.link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
                var randompostsurl = entry.link[j].href;
                var randomposts_date = entry.published.$t;
                if ('media$thumbnail' in entry) {
                    var randompoststhumb = entry.media$thumbnail.url
                } else {
                    randompoststhumb = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5SoVe1K6JSk/Utl0OOmucAI/AAAAAAAAF6E/hQghgD_EJdQ/s1600/no_thumb.png"
                }
            }
        };
        document.write('<li>');
        document.write('<a href="' + randompostsurl + '" rel="nofollow"><img alt="' + randompoststitle + '" src="' + randompoststhumb + '"/></a>');
        document.write('<div><a href="' + randompostsurl + '" rel="nofollow">' + randompoststitle + '</a></div>');
        if (randomposts_details == 'yes') {
            document.write('<span><div  class="random-info">' + randomposts_date.substring(8, 10) + '.' + randomposts_date.substring(5, 7) + '.' + randomposts_date.substring(0, 4) + ' - ' + randomposts_commentsnum) + '</div></span>'
        };
        document.write('<br/><div class="random-summary">' + randomposts_snippet + '</div><div style="clear:both"></div></li>')
    }
};
getvalue();
for (var i = 0; i < randomposts_number; i++) {
    document.write('<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&start-index=' + randomposts_current[i] + '&max-results=1&callback=random_posts\"><\/script>')
};
</script>
</ul>
```

I want to Improve the Image Quality..
In the img url its using the: s72-c size
How is it possible to force it use the most Quality image size? i think its s1600

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make changes to the following line (bold part will get added to the current code) -

```
var randompoststhumb = entry.media$thumbnail.url.replace(/s\B\d{2,4}-c/,'s1600');
```

This will alter the image URL by replacing `s72-c` instance with `s1600`